# Are AWS lambda@edge costs in addition to cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

We have very high AWS cloudfront costs.  It has been suggested that if some of our requests were served by lambda@edge, these costs could be reduced.

However, I am unsure if lambda@edge costs are in addition to cloudfront;  For example:

Cloudfront costs: $1.20 per million
lambda@edge costs: $ 0.20 per million (plus duration costs).

On the face of it, lambda@edge could be cheaper than Cloudfront.... Unless we have to pay Cloudfront also.

Can anyone tell me if using lambda@edge also incurs Cloudfront costs or not?

Comment: Lambda@edge is in addition to CloudFront. The content is still served by CloudFront.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda@edge is in addition to CloudFront. The content is still served by CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

CoudFront Functions are useful when running small scripts that are closest to users. Lambda@Edge Functions are better suited for more complex code that requires access to external services or the Internet and Lambda@Edge counts a request each time it starts executing in response to an Amazon CloudFront event globally.Lambda@Edge is an extension of AWS Lambda, a compute service that lets you execute functions that customize the content that CloudFront delivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lambda@Edge with Amazon CloudFront, you will pay for CloudFront + Lambda@Edge.

For example, if the requests come from the United States:
`$1.60/million requests` +
`$0.085/GB transfer` +
`function duration charges`.

It's important to remember that this service is very, very expensive and AWS will charge you for all requests regardless of WAF rate limiting unless you are able to spend $3,000/month on AWS Shield.